# Populating a null value in a listview using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently i am adding user medications, the user can add a medication with or without selecting a diagnosis, the diagnosis is gathered using a dropdown list based on the users current added 'diagnosis' which populate it.

[image]

When i fill out the form and select a diagnosis the data is added successfully into azure and on my next page which shows the listview off medications added , it successfully shows the medication added along with the diagnosis.

If i fill out the form and leave the diagnosis blank the data is posted to azure successfully and the diagnosisid goes in as blank, but on my next page which shows the listview off medications added it does not show it .

The data will not appear in the listview if the diagnosis is left blank.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets User Medication list
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The user meds.</returns>
    async public Task GetUserMedsMain()
    {


        MedicationList.ItemsSource = null;
        UserMedTimes.Clear(); //Clears the list before calling API (prevents duplication)

        main.Children.Add(MedicationList);
        main.Children.Remove(NoMeds);

        if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {

            main.Children.Remove(MedicationList);
            main.Children.Add(NoMeds);
            NoMeds.Text = "No Internet Connection - Please check your connection";
            NoMeds.Margin = new Thickness(35, 35, 20, 20);

            BusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        }

        else

        {
            BusyIndicator.IsRunning = true;

            //var usermed = await medicinemanager.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync<IEnumerable<usermedication>>("getusermednamejoin?userid=" + Helpers.Settings.UserKey + "", System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, null);

            try
            {


                var usermeddosagetime = await medicinemanager.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync("getusermednamejoin?userid=" + Helpers.Settings.UserKey, null, HttpMethod.Get, await App.LoadAPIKeyAsync(), null);



                var responseContent = await usermeddosagetime.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<UserMedDosagePayLoad>>(responseContent);

                //var usermeddosagetime = await medicinemanager.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync<IEnumerable<UserMedDosagePayLoad>>("getusermeddosagetime?userid=" + Helpers.Settings.UserKey + "", HttpMethod.Get, API, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
                //null, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, API, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

                Debug.WriteLine("UserMedDosageTime" + usermeddosagetime);

                foreach (UserMedDosagePayLoad item in user)
                {

                    UserMedTimes.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Currrently i am populating the listview using an API call in azure.

Comment: Did you check if your ListView itemsource is null when you do not have diagnosis somehow or does not have data at all?

Comment: @G.hakim When i first call the medications i check if the listview is null by : MedicationList.ItemsSource = null; .... I dont have any checks in place checking the diagnosis , not sure how to write it

Comment: Are you setting the item source to null is what you are telling me?

Comment: @MarkPW If itemsource of listview is null, then you should check why get null data from Azure under these circumstances.